# how can i make it responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i cant make responsive please help me. im using bootstrap `.container` structure for automatic design.
they are

`and they are css codes;`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24252a;
}

li, a, button {
    font-family: "Montserrat" , sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px 10%;
} 
.logo{
    cursor:pointer
}

.nav_links{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav_links li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav_links li a{
    transition: all 0.3 ease 0s;
}

.nav_links li a:hover{
    color:#0088a9
}
button{
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, alpha);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3 ease 0s;
    
}
button:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
}
```

`

i did try ".container" structure for automatic design. but this is not working and my codes are broken.i cant do this. please help me for responsive design. ive just started.

Comment: Please, give more information. Or share the git repository link for inspect.

Comment: Please share your markup structure, relevant CSS, and what you have tried and your results for a more thoughtful answer. Also, I don't see `.container` anywhere in your CSS block.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.